# How to clean a url with php without using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with a project I'm doing with PHP and it's in the URLs.

When I load a script like index.php everything works fine, the problem is when I load a script that is located within two or more directories.

In the URL the scripts with the routes begin to be enmeshed

Here is an example of the problem I have

[image]

I need to load a script, even if it is in several levels of nesting, make its functionality and in the url is reflected as:

I need to have something like this

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCLGQ.png): 
I thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: Add code snippet of what you tried so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP to achieve this. PHP is not responsible for determining if PHP (let along a particular PHP script) will handle any given URL.

You have to configure your webserver to do it. Since you mention .htaccess but provide no further information about your server, I'm going to assume you are using Apache HTTPD.

For Apache, that means using mod_rewrite, Alias or something similar. You can put the configuration for those tools in `.htaccess`, but you don't want to and [the documentation advises not to use them](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when).

So put your mod_rewrite or Alias configuration in the main Apache configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need an `htaccess` rule no matter what. However, it doesn't have to be a `mod_rewrite` rule. The reason you need this rule is because PHP is not responsible for the routing - it is merely responsible for the execution of your script.

The point of the rule is to direct apache and instruct it to execute the right script (in your case, `script32.php`) while keeping the request uri as intact as possible.

There are two ways around it, basically.

## Way 1 (cleaner): `mod_rewrite`

This is pretty straightforward, the set of rules you need are as follows:

```
# If the requested file name is a valid file/inode
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# ...or a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# ...then throw them straight on it
RewriteRule (.*) - [L]
# ...otherwise, redirect to script32.php with the full content of the request in query string
RewriteRule (.*) /welcome/script32.php?$1 [L]
```

The requested URL is now in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and you can now do whatever you like with it in PHP

## Way 2: catchall

This does not rely on `mod_rewrite` and may therefore be slightly faster. However, technically, it's a cheap hack. The way around it is as follows:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /welcome/script32.php
```

The requested URL can now be found in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and is available for parsing in PHP. However, with this, you've also disabled "legit" 404 errors from being generated through apache - and should make sure to obey proper behaviour in PHP to compensate.